# What is the slash before a signature name?

Tags: letter-writing

I sometimes have seen a signature like these:

/Fred

Why is this slash in a position here? What is it signify? More common is the simple

Fred

or maybe the

-Fred

. Alternate form here with a slash is not common so why the difference? Only a differing convention?

Comment: Is this in regards to email, or some other form of letter?

Comment: It seems that [the people who do it](https://www.donationcoder.com/forum/index.php?topic=10159.0) can't remember why...

Comment: What does a slash mean before a name signature in emails? https://www.answers.com/Q/What_does_a_slash_mean_before_a_name_signature_in_emails

Answer (score -3):

I started doing this in the mid-nighties. I was a web developer then. In HTML (code), you have an open and a closing tag. For instance, to make text appear bold, you wrap the word, like so: <b>**some bold text**</b>. This pair of Bs is called a tag. The second tag is called an end or close tag. Mentally, you're constantly reminding yourself "tag... (slash)end" because leaving out the end tag has ill effects. At some point it was just natural to sign emails with /[my name or initial]. 'Sincerely' felt realatively odd in that environment (no shoes!). Slash felt like the natural thing to close/end with. Now I'm old, and use 'regards' for formal/business email, but still use that slash otherwise.

During the (dot com) crash I recall seeing on a magazine cover (or billboard) the simple headline: </Netscape>? That slash had gotten serious. People knew what it meant.